# Unable to find package Microsoft.BotFramework.Composer.WebAppTemplates.Translation. No packages exist with this id in source(s)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm trying to add a package called "Microsoft.BotFramework.Composer.WebAppTemplates.Translation" in my C# project from Visual Studio code - PowerShell terminal.

This is the command I used:

```
dotnet add MyProjectName.csproj package Microsoft.BotFramework.Composer.WebAppTemplates.Translation
```

I'm getting following error:
Unable to find package Microsoft.BotFramework.Composer.WebAppTemplates.Translation. No packages exist with this id in the source(s): BotBuilder.myget.org, nuget.org

I've following two keys(nuget.org,BotBuilder.myget.org in my Nuget.Config file:

```
<add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
<add key="BotBuilder.myget.org" value="https://botbuilder.myget.org/F/botbuilder-v4-dotnet-daily/api/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
```

I cleared NuGet cache also using the following command. But no use.

```
dotnet.exe nuget locals all --clear
```

But still, I'm unable to understand why I'm getting the "No packages exist" error. Can someone please help me to solve this?

Comment: Why do you think that package exists? I've checked on nuget.org and there is no package with that name, and Google doesn't suggest anything either.

Comment: @RB - I've got the chatbot code from Github. The code is working for them. So if it's not in nuget.org, I think I need to search in some other package resource.

I'm beginner in dotnet, chatbot development. Can you suggest me what other package resources I can search for?

Comment: I'm assuming it's [this GitHub post](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/3514) you are talking about? In which case, I don't think the author of [the repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/17.multilingual-bot/Translation) has made it available as a NuGet package - it's just some sample code that you can take for your use (as long as you comply with the MIT license it is licensed under of course).

Comment: Yes. I'm talking about same GitHub post. Thank you for your reply. I've also commented on that GitHub post. I'll have to wait and see if author provides any help there

Comment: The code is available [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/17.multilingual-bot/Translation). You can just download it and use it as part of your project, or turn it into a nuget package yourself - as long as you comply with the MIT license (which is a very permissive license, so not hard to comply with).

Comment: @rb - Yes. I've already copied this translation folder into my project. I don't think this error is related to that folder. By the way, I stopped spending any more time on this issue as this package is not available. I'm now trying to build chatbot using their C# templates, rather than relying to bot composer generated code.